# I want a Windows compatible photo viewer that can do fullscreen without doing a slideshow

Tags: windows, photography

Looking at the Windows 10 "Photos" app, I cannot find a way to make it show the picture in fullscreen without running a slideshow. I installed the old Photo Gallery program, and then I realized that Windows 7 did not support this either! I either want a way to play a slideshow where it does not change pictures until I press a key, or I want a picture viewer that is capable of fullscreen viewing or a slideshow like I mentioned earlier.  Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I'm not a Windows user (and definitely not Win10) – but AFAIR a program called [IrfanView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IrfanView) should be capable of that.

Comment: try ImageGlass light weight and versatile photo viewer specially designed for windows

Comment: There might be some good choices at [this related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/image-photo-viewer-for-windows?rq=1).

Comment: pViewer worked for me -  https://sourceforge.net/projects/picoviewer/

Answer (score 6):

[Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/) is a great photo viewer. It will show individual photos, it has full screen display or part screen with menus and toolbars. It has 'next' and 'previous' photo commands in both modes. It can do slide shows.

It works fine on Windows 10 and I have used it on several other versions of Windows.

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote, but I'm not yet up to 15 rep for this stack.

Comment: somehow flagged by malwarebytes https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/6a67f079f8036a30e9e13fd9baecf0d37da18106050880a3f12845e445f8786f/detection

Comment: @d-coder  Irfanview has been a good program for several years. Perhaps you downloaded a bad imitation of it from a dodgy place. Also, the virus scanners make mistakes. There are fairly frequent reports of a good program being reported by an over zealos virus scanner. Of course you must be careful, perhaps download another copy from a good supplier, or try another scanner, or wait for an update to the scanner you have.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I think you may be right about the virus test results and how some of the scanners may be wrong about the thread existence. I however downloaded it from the correct site only. You can try uploading your copy of setup to virustotal. Again I agree scanners might make mistakes. :)

Answer (score 1):

[ImageGlass](https://imageglass.org/) is just perfect for the application. ImageGlass is another open source basic image viewer, which, while simple, benefits from the speed that comes with being so lightweight, and is a good choice for Windows users. ImageGlass supports the most common image formats, including GIF, PNG, WEBP, SVG, RAW,... You also can customize this extension list easily.

Answer (score 0):

[Xnview](https://www.xnview.com) is also really nice and does what you want. Personally, I like it better than Irfanview, but that's probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try out both! I would upvote, but I'm not yet up to 15 rep for this stack.